# Why is my network thermal printer printing images slowly from my Android phone?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, thermal-printer, escpos

I'm a flutter developer, i want to make a receipt for a resturant that needs the item names to print arabic on Network thermal printer, i have tried to use esc_pos_printer package to print but it doesn't print arabic, so i tried to generate an Image to use it to print the receipt, but the printer prints slowly
I have tried to print Image on Network thermal printer but it prints slowly,
I have Every thing downloaded the SDK from the manufacturer website, generated the Image but nothing worked I need help please

or Is there a workaround to print Arabic characters on a Network Thermal printer if esc_pos_printer package fails to do so in Flutter app?

i have tried to print the image on Network thermal printer but it's printed slowly
i expected it to be printed fast